# Stay within the scope of the class when using setInterval in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I have a class which manages my connection to my socket in NodeJS. Whenever a connection can not be established or is lost I want to set an interval to keep retrying to connect. However, if I call the `setInterval` function, the method I pass as a reference is now within the scope of `setInterval`. The methods in my socket class are now no longer available and I can't reconnect the socket unless I have some gigantic nested statements. The main problem is that the event listeners that I created in the `connect()` method are now no longer available inside the scope of `setInterval()`.

Any ideas on how to get this to work?

```
class SocketClass {

  constructor() {
    this.socket = {}
    this.port = 0
    this.host = ''
    this.intervalID = null
  }


  connect(port, host) {
    this.port = port;
    this.host = host;
    this.connectImpl()
    this.socket.on('error', () => this.errorEventHandler())
    this.socket.on('close', () => this.closeEventHandler())
  }

  connectEventHandler() {
    console.log('Connected!')
    if (this.intervalID !== null) {
      clearInterval(this.intervalID);
    }
  }

  errorEventHandler() {
    console.log('Error!')
  }

  connectImpl() {
    console.log('Trying to connect...')
    this.socket = require('net').Socket().connect(this.port, this.host)
  }

  closeEventHandler() {
    console.log('Connection lost')
    this.intervalID = setInterval(() => this.connectImpl(), 1000)
    // this.connectImpl() is called correctly but the event 
    // handlers defined in the constructor are now no longer bound
  }

}

export default new SocketClass
```

Comment: I find the downvotes unbelievably hard to fathom. My question is clear and simple including code. Some people really just like smashing that downvote button..

Comment: beats me - someone downvoted my perfectly good answer too...

Comment: As for clear: _"the method I pass as a reference is now within the scope of setInterval"_ - no, that's not correct.    _"The methods in my socket class are now no longer available"_ - not correct either.  _"the event listeners that I created in the connect() method are now no longer available inside the scope of setInterval() "_ - also not correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite what your comment says, you're not actually calling your `connectImpl` handler:

```
this.intervalID = setInterval(() => this.connectImpl(), 1000)
```

Without the extra parens, you're just passing a reference to an arrow function that *returns a reference to the `connectImpl` function*.

Re: your edit - you need to move the event handler registrations into the `connectImpl()` method.   When your timer fires those handlers remain registered on the *old* socket (but will disppear when it's garbage collected) and as currently written are not attached to the newly created socket.   This *is not* a scope related problem.

You also need to ensure that you call `clearInterval(this.intervalID)` in the `closeEventHandler` before you create a new timer because the "on close" handler is also called "on error" (for some errors, at least).

Comment: I accidentally pasted the code when it still had a typo. The comment was correct. The parentheses were already included in the code in my IDE. Nevertheless, in my initial post I clearly indicate that the scope of my class is no longer available inside `setInterval()` which is what I am trying to fix.

Comment: I answered the question you asked at the time.   Your other problem is that you need to register those handlers in the `connectImpl` method - the `this.socket` instance that you connect to the first time that has the handlers attached is not the same instance when you reconnect.

Comment: You actually didn't, because from my question it was obviously clear that I knew that those handlers were not registered within the scope of `setInterval()`. Besides that, registering them inside `connectImpl` will cause a memory leak since I constantly go into that method if I'm not connected.

Comment: You said you had a scope problem.  You didn't.  Nor will registering the handlers inside `connectImpl` create a leak because they're attached to an object that has only just been created, and the previous instance of which will be garbage collected.      You _cannot_ reassign to `this.socket` and expect that the previously registered handlers will then get attached to the new socket.